# Guardar en servidor una imagen previamente cargada en un img.src

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, fileupload

La situación es la siguiente:

Hay varias imágenes en un servidor de mi cliente que van nombradas 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc

Por razones diversas no me da un acceso FTP para bajarlas como debería, así que he creado un script en mi localhost que copia las imágenes, pero el problema es que a veces el siguiente código de php trabaja bien y a veces no:

**php**

```
$imgSize = @getimagesize('https://dominio.com/img/1.jpg');
```

Cuando **getimagesize** trae la información correcta puedo copiarla así:

**php**

```
$imgSize = @getimagesize('https://dominio.com/img/1.jpg');
if ($imgSize) {
    file_put_contents('img/imagen_1.jpg', file_get_contents('https://dominio.com/img/1.jpg'));
}
```

El problema como dije, es que a veces **getimagesize** si logra leer la información y a veces  simplemente **$imgSize** está vacío

Pero lo que siempre funciona es que puedo incluir la imagen directamente en un html así:

**html**

```
<img id="my_img" src="https://dominio.com/img/1.jpg">
```

Es justo aquí donde viene mi pregunta:

Existe alguna manera con jquery, php o lo que sea, de guardar esta imagen una vez cargada en un **img.src**?

Quizá estoy diciendo disparates, pero lo imagino algo así como:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <file id="my_file" name="my_file" >
</form>

<img id="my_img" src="https://dominio.com/img/1.jpg">

<script>
$(#my_file).val($('#my_img').prop('src'));
</script>
```

Y ya en el upload.php podría guardarlo así:

```
$_FILES[$_POST['my_img']]['tmp_name']
```

De alguna manera, transferir el valor de img.src a un file en un formulario, algo así.

Gracias por la ayuda ( :

Answer (score 0):

Copiado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/43015238/10531763

```js
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

Lo utiliza asi:

```js
toDataUrl(imagepath, function(myBase64) {
    console.log(myBase64); // myBase64 is the base64 string
});
```